# Storing data in the SQL table

Tags: sql

I am building web app for school project and I get some questions.

I am trying to build web hard-disk.

To store data, I used jave function to convert data to binary 
and then, I insert data into the sql data table

However,

First, I am sure that we can't storing more that 1.5G on the sql table. 
Is there anyway to store more than 2G data into the SQL table?

Second, If it is impossible, is there other ways to store data more than 2G. (like storing data to local hard disk. I mean, pretending local hard drive as web hard drive).

Comment: A "real" DBMS will not have such limitations. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am not sure.  I am using MySQL and MSsql.

Comment: For example in MySQL with Innodb tables the maximum tablespace size is four billion database pages (64TB) - I doubt you are going to hit that with a school project

Comment: hum... maybe I misunderstand... What I wanted to say is.. "If there is 2GB movie file and I wanna covert data to binary number and put into one sql table ". Is it fine to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to can do is store your file some where else like local hard drive or remote storage. and add the reference to the database. It is not a good practice to store such bulky data as a one data to the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or higher, the `varbinary(max)` data type will allow up to 2GB of binary in a single field (2^31-1, to be exact).

Also, `SELECT @@VERSION` will verify your version if you're running SQL Server.